# Getting more out of ubuntu

Tags: boot

I've been using Ubuntu 14.04 for a while now, but I'm not a proficient user. Today I' ve tried to understand how to boot a copy of windows 10 onto my laptop and run it in parallel with ubuntu; it doesn't seem difficult but I've stumbled upon many minor problems. For this reason, I'd like to understand how an operating system works at a deeper level. I'd like to know the basics.

I know this would be a really extensive question to answer, so what I'm really looking for would be a *book or internet link talking about this*. I'd really like to learn how an OS works, why it breaks, why you can sometimes repair it and sometimes not, what parts do all OSs have in common that makes you boot them in similar ways, stuff like that. 
Any useful link or book you guys could provide? It would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much! I know some tricks with the command shell and a little bit of programming, but hopefully one day I'll be able to contribute back.

Edit: as KGIII suggested, the following pages are recommended:

1) Ubuntu hand book . org
2) https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/784060-the-complete-beginners-guide-to-linux
3) http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/ossg/Introduction/intro.html

In particular, the third one seems to give a great deal of information about operating systems.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking, but as you said, it's a bit extensive, so I'm not sure how to best answer you.

There's a pretty good beginner's guide over on MakeUseOf that I wish I had found when I first got started with Ubuntu: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-an-absolute-beginners-guide/

Again, not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but HowStuffWorks has a pretty extensive explanation of what Ubuntu is and isn't: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/ubuntu1.htm

In my personal experience, I've learned a lot about Ubuntu since I first started using it, but I just learned as I went. It's a lot easier to learn as you go than it is to learn the entire workings of Ubuntu in one shot.

Comment: Add [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/), [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/784060-the-complete-beginners-guide-to-linux), and [this](http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/ossg/Introduction/intro.html) to your post if you want. These will go a long way in helping them out as well. Ping me, if you do.

Comment: Yeah, I think I imagined nothing of the precise kind existed; I just want a little crash course since otherwise one keeps seeing these random buzzwords and it takes longer to link them together and understand how everything works. I think you guys accomplished that... Thanks!